# Fixed Positioning Not Working on Current iOS/Android Devices?

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a fixed position nav bar that's "fixing" to the bottom of the page and not the bottom of the viewport as intended on mobile/tablet devices.

I'm aware that older mobile OS/browser versions may not have supported fixed positioning, but I don't believe that's the issue here - Tested on Chrome/Safari with iPad3 (iOS6+) and Chrome on a Kindle Fire (Android 4+).

Each of the fixed position elements are tied to a jQuery event - Either a scroll or click event depending on the element.  I haven't read of that causing an issue, but I've included the code in case there's a connection.

If someone sees something I'm missing, I'd greatly appreciate the help.  I'm trying to avoid a jQuery solution if possible as from everything I've read, this shouldn't be an issue with current devices.

I've read through a number of related questions and have tried the following:

**Locking the viewport scalability:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

**I've played with webkit transform and backface-visibility:**

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

**My CSS:**

```
.main-links {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: .7em;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  z-index:999999;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
```

**jQuery:**

```
     var $mainLinks = $('.main-links');
     var $headerLogo = $('.header-logo');

 $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

  $mainLinks.fadeIn();
  $headerLogo.fadeIn();

} else {

  $mainLinks.hide();
  $headerLogo.hide();
}
```

[Link to my working copy of the page in question](http://www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/bwh/index.html)

Comment: I guess the jquery pervents it to work, mobile device browsers are not like pc's browsers, they are "lite" version of the real thing and they cannot run everything though the fixed position should be work fine, try remove jquery for mobile only and it will work.

Comment: @ExCluSiv3 - Appreciate the feedback, but I'd like to think there's a specific issue/conflict somewhere.  As a test however, I deleted all of my jQuery script and added inline CSS as display:block to .main-links.    Still fixing to page and not viewport.